# Google Chart URL can not be loaded by WebView (NSUrl remains nil)

Tags: ios4, nsurl, google-visualization

I try to load an URL from Google Chart in a UIWebView. Here is the interesting code:

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxr=0,5,398.333&chxs=0,676767,11.167,0.833,l,676767&chxt=x&chs=300x225&cht=lc&chco=3D79FF&chd=s:ilowy0zvvzrligikqsrl&chg=14.3,-1,0,0&chls=2&chm=B,C5D4EABB,0,0,0|R,FF0000,0,0,0.03|R,000000,0,0.3,0.33";

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

if (url == nil) {
    NSLog(@"URL error occured");
} else {

   NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
     [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

The message "URL error occured" is logged.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution on my own:

The NSUrl object does not accept pipes (|) within an URL. One has to escape the pipes by replacing them with %7c

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *str =@"http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chf=bg,s,00000000&chs=300x225&cht=p3&chco=E91616|0000FF&chd=t:50,21&chp=2.9&chma=0,0,0,7";
str = [str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *chartURL = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
```

Use like this.